# What is the "number of partitions" and "range" of an array?

Tags: arrays, sorting

As per MSDN doc for [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx),

> If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * logN, where N is the range of the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.

What I don't know is what are the "number of partitions" and the "range" of an array. What are they?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson If it's written on MSDN, then it matters. Otherwise they wouldn't have written on the MSDN.

Comment: @Sayse might want to explain a tree...

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson - You can go to any wikipedia page for a sorting algorithm to find that (i.e Quicksort). That wasn't what the question was, feel free to submit your own answer  building upon my comment

Comment: @Sayse Now I'm intrigued... So if he recurses too much (with each recursion that "generates" two partitions, if I remember QuickSort well), then it stop recursing and uses HeapSort? Because the "standard" implementation of QuickSort I've ever seen is simply recursive (in truth it normally uses a stack to "simulate" recursion) until the partitions are small enough to use another algorithm

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Yes, in some cases it's important for a programmer to know how a collection is being sorted. For instance if I have something like `B1, A1, C1, A2` and *I only want to sort the letters*, I expect `A1, A2, B1, C1`, but Quicksort **could** give me `A2, A1, B1, C1`, that's because Quicksort is *not stable*.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Implementation of `Sort` is a standard job interview question... I think that knowing of a possible optimization like that can give points (to the standard QuickSort + other algorithm or Timsort)

Comment: @xanatos - The full quote from where the OP got their quote from says that Array.Sort will use an [introsort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, everyone. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Sayse I think you should write at least a small response

Comment: @Sayse wikipedia URL you mentioned sums it well. Can you please add it to answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partition in a sort is basically a section of the list based upon a pivot point. For example, using the quick sort algorithm to sort the following:

```
                First Pass          Second Pass
3              3                     1
8              1                     3
5 <- Pivot     5---------            5
1              8                     7
7              7                     8
```

In the first pass, there are *two* partitions based off numbers that are less than or greater than **5**

The range is the difference between the largest and smallest values, so in this example that is **7** (8 - 1)

So the line you are questioning works as

```
 (2 * log(7)) > 2    == Use HeapSort
 1.691 > 2              false
```

Comment: Help! I have the same question as the OP and this answer doesn't clarify it for me. The MSDN page is about a Sort method that works for arrays of any type, you are assuming we are sorting numbers! How does this work (especially the "range") if I am sorting Strings? Second, you are referring to the "first pass" - Why only one pass? Third, what is so important about the range? What is so different about sorting [1,2,3,4] or [-100,0,100,99999] that you would need two completely different algorithms to perform these tasks?

Comment: [According to the Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs,705), the "range" of the array is in fact its length, not the difference between its largest and smallest values. (I was a bit confused; it seemed unlikely that `Array.Sort` might perform a min/max on the array before it started.)

Comment: (2 * log(7)) doesn't seem to be equal to 1.691. How did you come up with that number?

Comment: @null - This was 9 years ago and I honestly can't remember